# How To write Popup Link

Tags: cakephp

Hello Everyone I am beginner. 
This is Lightbox script and this one working very well in php. 
Now i want to write same thing in cake php so how can i write this. 
And location of my image is

Inside cakephp folder.

app/view/themed/default/webroot/upload

```
<a data-gal="prettyPhoto[portfolio1]" href="upload/
<?php echo $aGalleries[$i]['gallery']['picture'];?>">
<i class="icon-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: please explain better: the location you are talking abour is inside cakephp img folder? i.e. app/webroot/img/themed/default/webroot/upload

Comment: @arilia yes i just updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="icon-plus"></i>', 
    array('action' => 'upload', $aGalleries[$i]['gallery']['picture']),
    array('data-gal' => 'prettyPhoto[portfolio1]', 'escape' => false)
);
```

edit: after reading your edits

as suggested in http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/themes.html you have to create a link to your folder inside the application webroot. After that you can do:

so that `app/webroot/theme/default/upload/` points to `app/View/Themed/default/webroot/upload/`

```
echo $this->Html->link(
   '<i class="icon-plus"></i>', 
    FULL_BASE_URL.'/webroot/theme/default/upload/'.$aGalleries[$i]['gallery']['picture'],
    array('data-gal' => 'prettyPhoto[portfolio1]', 'escape' => false)
);
```